# How to convert sparse matrix to dense matrix in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia, sparse-matrix

How do you convert a sparse matrix to a dense matrix in Julia? According to [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/sparse-to-dense-matrix/8380) I should be able to use `full` or `Matrix`, however `full` is evidently not standard in the SparseArrays module, and when I try to use `Matrix`:

```
    I = []
    J = []
    A = []

    for i in 1:3
        push!(I, i)
        push!(J, i^2)
        push!(A, sqrt(i))
    end

    sarr = sparse(I, J, A, 10, 10)
    arr = Matrix(sarr)
```

I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: MethodError
MethodError: no method matching zero(::Type{Any})
```

Comment: Writing `[]` creates a `Vector{Any}` which is a terrible thing. Never use `[]`, you must make sure it has an element type, like `Int[]`or `Float64[]`. If you see `A = []` in your code, it means it will be extremely slow, and possibly fail.

Comment: I switched it to I=Int[], J=Int[] and A=Float64[] and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to do `collect(sarr)` or `Matrix(sarr)`.

Note, however that your code uses untyped containers which is not recommended. Indexes in arrays are `Int`s so it should be:

```
I = Int[]
J = Int[]
A = Float64[]

for i in 1:3
    push!(I, i)
    push!(J, i^2)
    push!(A, sqrt(i))
end

sarr = sparse(I, J, A, 10, 10)
```

Now you can do:

```
julia> collect(sarr)
10×10 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.41421  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.73205  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
```